# Home-brew OpenMPI installation issue

Tags: homebrew, openmpi

I am having an issue installing OpenMPI using Home-brew, having searched around I have not been able to find any answers for this. I am doing this because when installing an R package from GitHub I am receiving this error:

```
clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
```

The advice seems to be that in this case one should reinstall openmpi using homebrew. When I do that I get the following response:

```
brew reinstall openmpi --build-from-source
==> Reinstalling open-mpi 
==> Downloading https://download.open-mpi.org/release/open-mpi/v3.1/openmpi-3.1.2.tar.bz2
Already downloaded: /Users/Dom/Library/Caches/Homebrew/open-mpi--3.1.2.tar.bz2
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/open-mpi/3.1.2 --disable-silent-rules --enable-ipv6 --with-libevent=/usr/local/opt/libevent --with-sge
Last 15 lines from /Users/Dom/Library/Logs/Homebrew/open-mpi/01.configure:
checking to see if Fortran compilers need additional linker flags... -Wl,-flat_namespace
checking  external symbol convention... single underscore
checking if C and Fortran are link compatible... yes
checking to see if Fortran compiler likes the C++ exception flags... skipped (no C++ exceptions flags)
checking to see if mpifort compiler needs additional linker flags... -Wl,-commons,use_dylibs
checking if Fortran compiler supports CHARACTER... yes
checking size of Fortran CHARACTER... 1
checking for C type corresponding to CHARACTER... char
checking alignment of Fortran CHARACTER... 1
checking for corresponding KIND value of CHARACTER... C_SIGNED_CHAR
checking KIND value of Fortran C_SIGNED_CHAR... no ISO_C_BINDING -- fallback
checking Fortran value of selected_int_kind(4)... no
configure: WARNING: Could not determine KIND value of C_SIGNED_CHAR
configure: WARNING: See config.log for more details
configure: error: Cannot continue
```

I seem to be going further down a rabbit hole I don't really understand, I have run brew doctor and it advises me that there are a bunch of .config files etc which could confound it but I'm not keen on deleting/moving those files as I don't know if they are dependencies for other things. Could anyone set me straight here?

Many Thanks for any responses

Comment: IIRC, Open MPI from Homebrew is built with gcc from Homebrew (and not clang from OSX) so you might want to double check gcc is installed and resolves to the GNU compiler.

Comment: Thanks Gilles, I have installed gcc-8.2.0 from Home Brew. I notice there is also another installation of gcc as well which presumably Clang uses

Comment: I have now fixed this, had to delete and re-install home brew and reinstalled it with the various additional part (gcc etc). The R issue was resolved by updating the R Makevars file to direct it to the compiler